# @ngrx/store: Strange error when using a single reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx-store

I have a small app that I am using as a demo for a client, but I am having trouble using just a single reducer. An extract of my `AppModule` looks like this:

```
export function rootReducerFactory() {
  return reducer;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({}, {
      reducerFactory: rootReducerFactory
    })
    // other imports
  ],
  declarations: [
    // some declarations
  ],
  providers: [
    // some providers
  ]
})
export class WeatherModule { }
```

This works as expected when my reducer signature looks like this:

```
export function reducer( state: State = initialState, action: WeatherActionsUnion )
{ 
    // reducer code
}
```

However, if I try to strongly-type the return of the reducer, like this:

```
export function reducer( state: State = initialState, action: WeatherActionsUnion ): State
{ 
    // reducer code
}
```

..., which I need to do, I get a compile-time error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionReducerMap | InjectionToken

...which pertains to the `StoreModule.forRoot()` call I'm making. What am I doing wrong?

I did try this:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
  reducerFactory: rootReducerFactory
})
```

...and although there are no longer errors at compile time, the reducer does not get called.

Comment: I'm not sure about version, but have you tried to use mapping instead of factories? https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/api.md#initial-state
I mean use {reducer: reducer} as a first argument. And initial state as a second.